# What does a media server need?

Tags: server, wireless, email, networking, mediaserver

I want to buy a new PC to be used as a media server that streams HD movies, music to any wireless device on my network (laptop, desktop, TV, etc.).

1. I was wondering about the PC hardware's specifications that I need to have so that it can work just fine? (It will be wireless)
2. Is there any tutorial showing how it could be done?
3. And the security - how can I secure it?
4. As well as I need it to to host my emails. I mean I have many emails. And sometimes I'm using desktop, sometimes laptop.. so is it possible to make the server store a copy of my emails, attachments, all sent items (whether they were from desktop or laptop)?

Comment: I Would split this question in to 4 separate questions so that a more detailed answer can be given for each. You can ask as many questions as you like!

Answer (score 3):

As @Allan commented, this is pretty large question. Therefore, I'll give rather short answers.

### Hardware

It depends how you are going to stream it. If you mean just sharing files, then almost anything with big enough hard disks. If you want to stream HD movies, then you'll need plenty of power.

As of wireless: either you'll need wireless card (PCI or USB), or if you can connect it to your wireless access point, then just cables.

### Tutorials

Google is your friend. For example

- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/using-your-linux-computer-as-a-media-center-part-1/
- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-great-linux-media-cente-distributions-transform-tv/

### Security

General rules apply. Use secure passwords. Keep your software up-to-date. Do not allow random computers to your LAN (use WPA for wi-fi and so on). If you want it to be really more secure, you can use IPSec to encrypt connections between devices. However, most probably that's quite big overkill.

### Emails

You can setup for example postfix and dovecot to allow IMAP access from other computers. You can found tutorials for this for example from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer). If you need specific help with setting up email server, add separate question. If you don't have really huge amount of emails (talk about hundred gigabyte or so), then common hardware can handle it easily.

Comment: @DeaDSouL: if that answered your question, you should accept it as an answer.